# Choosing apples and bananas

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are 3 green apples, 5 yellow apples, 4 green bananas, and 6 yellow bananas. You are to select two at random. What is the probability of selecting a banana and an apple given that both are yellow?

We have $Pr(\text{apple and banana | both are yellow})=Pr(\text{yellow apple and yellow banana})/Pr(\text{both are yellow})$.

We have 11 yellow apples and yellow bananas, and there are $C(11,2)$ ways to choose two of them. The numerator is $C(11,2)/C(18,2)$. There are also 11 yellow fruits, and there are again $C(11,2)$ ways to choose two yellow fruits. The denominator turns out to be the same. This doesn't look right. Where am I mistaken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy way:

Since it is given that both pieces of fruit are yellow, pretend that the green fruit do not exist.

Probability is

$$\frac{N\text{(umerator)}}{D\text{(enominator)}}$$

where $D = \binom{11}{2}$.

Then $N = \binom{5}{1} \times \binom{6}{1}.$

Explanation:

$D$ represents the total number of ways of selecting two pieces of yellow fruit.

$N$ represents the total number of ways of selecting one yellow apple and one yellow banana.

**Addendum**
Responding to comment question:

The more formal approach is to use [Bayes Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem).

That is, given events $R,S$ you have that

$p(R|S) = \frac{p(RS)}{p(S)}.$

Let $(R)$ denote the event of 1 yellow apple and 1 yellow banana being chosen.

Let $(S)$ denote the event that two yellow pieces of fruit were chosen.

You want $p(R|S)$.

$p(RS) = [(5/18)\times (6/17)] + [(6/18)\times (5/17)].$

The above expression has two terms, which represents that you can choose either the yellow apple first, or the yellow banana first.

$p(RS)$ simplifies to $\frac{2 \times 5 \times 6}{18 \times 17}.$

$p(S) = 11/18 \times 10/17.$

So $\frac{p(RS)}{p(S)} = \frac{2 \times 5 \times 6}{11 \times 10}.$

Comment: That makes sense. But I'm still wondering what's wrong with my argument with the conditional probability formula...

Comment: @user660670 See the Addendum to my answer.

Comment: @user660670 Nothing was wrong with the formula; it was the event.  The conditional probability for obtaining *two yellow fruit* when you select two yellow fruit is of course equal to one.  It is just that you actually wanted the conditional probability for obtaining *one yellow apple **and** one yellow banana* when you select two yellow fruit.

Comment: @GrahamKemp true, but the OP wanted to know where he went wrong.  Therefore, in my Addendum, I wanted to apply Bayes Theorem in such a way that (similar to the OP's work), the denominator of $(18 \times 17)$ was involved.

Comment: The  op only went awry with identifying the joint event as "obtaining two from the yellow apples and banananas" .

Answer (score 0):

> We have 11 yellow apples and yellow bananas, and there are C(11,2) ways to choose two of them.

The joint event is not just of obtaining two from the eleven yellow apples and bananas, rather it is of obtaining specifically *one from the six* yellow bananas and *one from the five* yellow apples. (When selecting any *two* from all *eighteen* fruit.)

$$\left.{^{6}\mathrm C_1}{^{5}\mathrm C_1}\middle/{^{18}\mathrm C_2}\right.$$

The conditioning event *is* of obtaining two from the eleven yellow fruit, when making that selection.

$$\left.{^{11}\mathrm C_2}\middle/{^{18}\mathrm C_2}\right.$$

So the conditional probability is the ratio (where the common factor is cancelled).

$$\left.{^{6}\mathrm C_1}{^{5}\mathrm C_1}\middle/{^{11}\mathrm C_2}\right.$$